# How to run "dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates" noninteractively?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I would like default to "accept" new certificate. I have tried the following.

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive ca-certificates
```

It runs, but the CA is not added.

If not possible, is it OK to directly modify /etc/ca-certificates.conf?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

no this won't work out of the box.

Based on http://blog.sandipb.net/2009/08/08/adding-new-ca-certificates-in-ubuntu-jaunty/, you can do the following sequence that doesn't need interactive selection:

```
sudo cp my.cert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

tested and works on debian 5/6.

Comment: Only worked for me if I used `.crt` for the extension instead. Running Debian 8.3

Comment: That's right @nVitius - if you've got a `PEM` certificate you need to convert it into `.crt` format first: `openssl x509 -in foo.pem -inform PEM -out foo.crt`

Comment: @bossi If i remember correctly, I was referring to `.cert` vs `.crt`. Only the latter seemed to work for me.

Comment: @nVitiusYes - that was my understanding as well, that the certificates need to be provided either strictly in `PEM`-encoded format and suffixed `.crt` format or only encoded in `PEM` format (no matter the extension given) - not sure if `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` filters by file extension. `.cer`/`.cert` (?) is the Microsoft equivalent to the *nix common `.crt` extension (and wraps differently encoded data afaik) while `.crt` files are usually `PEM` (ascii base64 armored) or `DER` (binary) encoded.

Comment: I assume `dpkg-reconfigure ca-centificates` expects ascii PEM encoded data but haven't confirmed that. [Here's some further info](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can specify minimum priority question to show using param -p with valid priorities (low medium high critical). If you set it to critical, should work fine for your scenario.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p critical ca-certificates
```